# Fail to set default WHERE clause with parameter

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

I have a question: how to set default value of the parameter i JasperReport's report? I have tried sth like this:

```
<parameter name="where" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1 = 1]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

and include this parameter to my queryString:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT *
      FROM "TABLE"
      where $P{where}]]>
</queryString>
```

But I have an error. I also tried to set this value in java, for instance 1.equals(1) but it still doesn't work. I have to set in this parameter a condition which is always true. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it's not work, you try build dynamic sql.
Jasper not support dynamic sql.

My solution:

```
<parameter name="where" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

and query:

```
<queryString>
<![CDATA[SELECT *
  FROM "TABLE"
  where ('1' = $P{where} or any_column = $P{where})]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this problem. Solution is simple. I have done everything right but `<![CDATA[1 = 1]]>` should be replaced by `<![CDATA["1 = 1"]]>`. Second step is to ad "!" after $P declaration like this: `where $P!{where}`.
And now everything works fine. I hope this help others.